# Send mail with parameters from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, email

I already know how to send emails using sql server mail, what I do for this is create a table and then I use something like this for the table body:

```
set @Body = 
( ColName as [TD],
Col2Name as [TD] from tableName for xml raw ('tr'), elements)
```

That works fine but now I don't want to select anything form any table, I want to do something like this (Fill table body with data from stored procedure parameters):

```
set @Body = 
( @Parameter1 as [TD],
@Parameter2 as [TD]  for xml raw ('tr'), elements)
```

But it doesn't work, which is the correct way to do this?

PD. With the above code I get the following sql server error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'as'

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here... but it sounds like you should look at the `@query` or one of the `@attach_query_result_as_file` type parameters to sp_send_dbmail

Comment: @scsimon I have everything to send the email and works fine, but the table body is filled selecting data from a table, now I want to fill table body but using parameters

Comment: So you want the @body to be the query results from a query which uses parameters?

Comment: @scsimon The above code is part of an stored procedure, I want to fill table body using parameters of that stored procedure.

Comment: Your last comment sounds like you want to fill the body with whatever the values of the parameters are--but that isn't what you syntax suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
set @Body = 
( @Parameter1 as [TD],
@Parameter2 as [TD]  for xml raw ('tr'), elements)
```

To:

```
set @Body = 
( Select @Parameter1 as [TD],
@Parameter2 as [TD]  for xml raw ('tr'), elements)
```

Remember that you are selecting something, so you need to use Select.